# Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.duncansolutions.databus.bean.Fdjobs

Tags: java

In my code

```
 List<Fdjobs> fdjobs=new ArrayList<Fdjobs>();
        fdjobs = (ArrayList<Fdjobs>)genericDao.namedQuery(Fdjobs.QUERYJOBS, hm);
Integer deactivateValue=new Integer(0);
 for (Fdjobs job : fdjobs) {
            job.setActiveJob(deactivateValue);
            job.addFDJobHistory();
            genericDao.update(job);

        }
```

if the size of the result list fdjobs is zero i dont get ant error but if the size is more than zero i am getting the error

```
[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.duncansolutions.databus.bean.Fdjobs
```

Comment: Add the signature for `Fjobs.setActiveJob()` and `Fjobs.addFDJobHistory()`. I believe `setActiveJob()` expects `FJobs` and not an `Object`/`int`

Comment: Thanks for correction,i added the signature to job.setActiveJob(deactivateValue),it expects integer object.from the log file error was pointing to for loop,how do i go about it

Answer (score 0):

`nameQuery()` method not returning the Type

```
 ArrayList<Fdjobs>
```

please debug it. you can use

```
ArrayList<Object>
```

for this.

Comment: No, it would have been a different type in the error if it was the case. It would say it cannot convert it to `ArrayList<Fjobs>`.

Comment: yes this could be be. but depends on the return type. if query return a single result not a list.

Answer (score -1):

The error is simple: you get a `Object[]` (`[Ljava.lang.Object`) instead of a `Fdjobs` object in the `List` returned from your `namedQuery`.

So the bug is either in your for-each loop or in `namedQuery` which depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: But the casting is nmot to `Fdjobs` it is to `ArrayList<Fdjobs>`. I would have expected if it was the case that the error will be:  [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: The cast does not fail at `ArrayList` it fails on the `for` loop, as can be seen from the exception message. The value returned from 'namedQuery' is in fact a `ArrayList<?>` but the values inside the list aren't `Fdjobs` but `Object[]`.

Comment: @Neet the error in the log file was pointing to for loop.how do i debug to verify the type of values returned is fdjobs or not

Comment: Well, you could do a for-each like `for(final Object o : fdjobs)` and then check each object using `instanceof`. Or you can just fix the DAO method (if you have access to it).